# Echoed text showing up in wrong place

Tags: php, html, css, web

I'm creating a page with PHP for a class and when I echo things it shows up in the wrong place.

Here is my HTML page

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>About</h1>

        <form action="Insert.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>First name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Last name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Age:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="age"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP page:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
if(!$con) {
    die("could not connect to localhost:" .mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("a7068104_world") or die("Cannot connect to database");

header("refresh:1.5; url=NamesAction.php");

$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname'] . " " . $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM names_1 WHERE fullname='$fullname'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
        echo "Your name is already in the database and will not be added again!";
}
else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO names_1 (firstname, lastname, fullname, age) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname', '$fullname', '$age')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result) {
            echo "Your name was successfully added to the database!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Your name couldn't be added to the database!";
        }
}

mysql_close($con);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Names</h1>
        <p>You will be redirected back to the <b>Names</b> page in a moment.</p>
        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I echo stuff in my PHP page it shows up at the very top of the frame that it's in right above the

```
<div id="main">
```

I want the echoed text to go in the very bottom of the

```
<div id="main">
```

Is there any way that I can do that? I appreciate your help!

Thanks,
Leonardude

Comment: Could be your CSS. Post a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are *echo'ing* the message before you supply your HTML.
Which is evident here:

```
        if($result) {
            echo "Your name was successfully added to the database!";
        }
        else{
            echo "Your name couldn't be added to the database!";
        }
```

Because **PHP** is a server-side language and HTML is client-side, the PHP will process well before the HTML, meaning it will echo before the page is displayed. Hence the issue where it is before your `<div id="main"></div>`.

A way around this is by setting a variable

```
        if($result) {
            $var = "Your name was successfully added to the database!";
        }
        else{
            $var = "Your name couldn't be added to the database!";
        }
```

And somewhere in your `<div id="main"></div>` you could do something like the following:

```
<div id="main">

<?php 
    if(isset($var) && !empty($var)) {
        echo $var;
    }

?>

</div>
```